# Fail to install vim solarized

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I am struggling on the installation of solarized plugin on vim, the following are the steps I followed

1. Use gmarik/Vundle.vim to install the solarized plugin (with the below .vimrc script)
2. Run vim +PluginInstall +qall to install the plugin
3. Put the following lines in the .vimrc:

> syntax enable
>   set background=dark
>   colorscheme solarized

.vimrc script used
[image: vimrc script]

But outcome the solarized plugin comes with following results which look and feel are not as expected
[image: bad look and feel]

Expecting look
[image]
Is there anything I have done wrong? Please advice. Thanks and appreciate everyone for the kind help

Try to add

`set t_Co=256
let g:solarized_termcolors=256`

Looks better, but still different from the capture shown by the author
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the output of `:colorscheme`, `:set t_Co` and `:echo $TERM` in Vim?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, :set t_Co >> t_Co=256, :echo $TERM >> xterm

Comment: I have the same but only in UXterm.

Comment: If `$TERM == xterm`, you won't get 256 colours, check the value of  [`let g:solarized_termcolors`](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/vim-colors-solarized#advanced-configuration). Do you have a 256-colour terminal available on your system?

Comment: Have you solved this? I have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem once. I guess the easiest way to do this is using [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen). To install pathogen, from console:

```
    mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle; \
curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim \
    https://raw.github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/master/autoload/pathogen.vim
```

Then add this to your .vimrc:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
```

Now you can install plugins into ~/.vim/bundle which will be automatically loaded to vim. To install solarized theme, simply add [vim-colors-solarized](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized) plugin:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone git://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized.git
```

The rest you have, which is setting t_Co to 256 and setting colorscheme to solarized. You may also try:

```
set t_Co = 256
```

Finally changing terminal emulator's color scheme to solarized might help. Or if you don't want to do this, add this line in .vimrc before setting your colorscheme to solarized:

```
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, better this time (still using vundle), after adding set t_Co = 256 and let g:solarized_termcolors=256 , but the look and feel still differ from the author shown in github (image captured in first thread)

Answer (score 1):

I used vim-plug to add solarize. In .vimrc I added...

```
if empty(glob('~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim'))   silent !curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
        \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim   autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall --sync | source $MYVIMRC endif call 
plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'

call plug#end()

set background=dark

colorscheme solarized
```

Then after saving and closing, I run this to install

```
vim +'PlugInstall --sync' +qa
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I never managed to get vim-colors-solarized working but instead the solarized8 plugin worked perfectly for me. I guess the question is no longer relevant after 6 years, but here's my solarized setup.

I have iTerm2 with its solarized dark color theme. My term is set to xterm-256color, I have vim-plug on top of neovim, my init.vim plugin for solarized8 looks like:
`Plug 'lifepillar/vim-solarized8'`

Then I have these lines that set up proper colors:

```
set termguicolors
let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"

set background=dark
colorscheme solarized8
syntax enable
```

I also have the vim-sensible plugin but I'm not entirely sure if that has any effect for this.

Good luck to anyone who's also trying to get solarized dark working in vim.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following in your vimrc:

`set background=dark`

*before* you activate the colorscheme.

EDIT: have just reread your question and realised you already do this. Apologies!

Answer (score 0):

`set term=foo` is *useless*: the `TERM` environment variable should be set by your terminal emulator or, baring that, in your shell's `*rc` file.

Supposing you use CLI Vim, you can obtain something that looks like that screenshot if you set your terminal emulator up to use [the solarized palette](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized#the-values).